# Equivalent of MySQL's `show processlist` in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Is there an equivalent of `MySQL`'s command `show processlist;` in `Apache SparkSQL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing the answer myself here (got some tip from my colleagues).

There may be no direct equivalent commands in SparkSQL, but one can use the WebUI for Spark to achieve similar effects.

c.f. [Monitoring and Instrumentation (Official Doc of Apache Spark)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)